# Category Search using Foursquare returns wrong Category

Tags: java, json, foursquare

I'm doing a category search for food but I'm getting things like Bridges back.  Can somebody please verify I'm structuring the URL correctly and if so, possibly point out what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you so much in advance.

URL (blocked out the sensitive stuff like client id and secret):
**https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?client_id=PUT_YOUR_CLIENT_ID_HERE&client_secret=PUT_YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET_HERE&v=20140714&ll=40.7,-74&radius=1000&category=4d4b7105d754a06374d81259**

The category ID I'm using is from foursquare's website.  It's the ID for 'Food'
You can see the list of IDs [Right Here](https://developer.foursquare.com/categorytree)

Here's my response in json (edited for size):

```
{
  "meta": {
    "code": 200
  },
  "response": {
    "venues": [
      {
        "id": "430d0a00f964a5203e271fe3",
        "name": "Brooklyn Bridge Park",
        "contact": {
          "phone": "2128033822",
          "formattedPhone": "(212) 803-3822",
          "twitter": "nycparks",
          "facebook": "104475634308",
          "facebookUsername": "BartowPell",
          "facebookName": "Bartow-Pell Mansion Museum"
        },
        "location": {
          "address": "Main St",
          "crossStreet": "Plymouth St",
          "lat": 40.70227697066692,
          "lng": -73.9965033531189,
          "distance": 389,
          "postalCode": "11201",
          "cc": "US",
          "city": "Brooklyn",
          "state": "NY",
          "country": "United States",
          "formattedAddress": [
            "Main St (Plymouth St)",
            "Brooklyn, NY 11201",
            "United States"
          ]
        },
        "categories": [
          {
            "id": "4bf58dd8d48988d163941735",
            "name": "Park",
            "pluralName": "Parks",
            "shortName": "Park",
            "icon": {
              "prefix": "https:\/\/ss3.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/parks_outdoors\/park_",
              "suffix": ".png"
            },
            "primary": true
          }
        ],
        "verified": true,
        "stats": {
          "checkinsCount": 28131,
          "usersCount": 17548,
          "tipCount": 177
        },
        "url": "http:\/\/nyc.gov\/parks",
        "specials": {
          "count": 0,
          "items": [

          ]
        },
        "hereNow": {
          "count": 15,
          "summary": "15 people are checked in here",
          "groups": [
            {
              "type": "others",
              "name": "Other people here",
              "count": 15,
              "items": [

              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "referralId": "v-1429381004"
      },
      {
        "id": "4a43bcb7f964a520bba61fe3",
        "name": "Brooklyn Bridge",
        "contact": {
          "twitter": "nyc_dot",
          "facebook": "166279802886",
          "facebookUsername": "NYCDOT",
          "facebookName": "NYC DOT"
        },
        "location": {
          "address": "Brooklyn Bridge",
          "lat": 40.705953265881305,
          "lng": -73.99656772613525,
          "distance": 723,
          "postalCode": "10038",
          "cc": "US",
          "city": "New York",
          "state": "NY",
          "country": "United States",
          "formattedAddress": [
            "Brooklyn Bridge",
            "New York, NY 10038",
            "United States"
          ]
        },
        "categories": [
          {
            "id": "4bf58dd8d48988d1df941735",
            "name": "Bridge",
            "pluralName": "Bridges",
            "shortName": "Bridge",
            "icon": {
              "prefix": "https:\/\/ss3.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/parks_outdoors\/bridge_",
              "suffix": ".png"
            },
            "primary": true
          }
        ],
        "verified": true,
        "stats": {
          "checkinsCount": 120787,
          "usersCount": 67456,
          "tipCount": 534
        },
        "url": "http:\/\/www.nyc.gov\/dot",
        "specials": {
          "count": 0,
          "items": [

          ]
        },
        "hereNow": {
          "count": 18,
          "summary": "18 people are checked in here",
          "groups": [
            {
              "type": "others",
              "name": "Other people here",
              "count": 18,
              "items": [

              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "storeId": "",
        "referralId": "v-1429381004"
      },
      {
        "id": "51eabef6498e10cf3aea7942",
        "name": "Brooklyn Bridge Park - Pier 2",
        "contact": {

        },
        "location": {
          "address": "Furman St",
          "crossStreet": "Brooklyn Bridge Park Greenway",
          "lat": 40.69956454780675,
          "lng": -73.99835740533105,
          "distance": 146,
          "cc": "US",
          "city": "Brooklyn",
          "state": "NY",
          "country": "United States",
          "formattedAddress": [
            "Furman St (Brooklyn Bridge Park Greenway)",
            "Brooklyn, NY",
            "United States"
          ]
        },
        "categories": [
          {
            "id": "4bf58dd8d48988d163941735",
            "name": "Park",
            "pluralName": "Parks",
            "shortName": "Park",
            "icon": {
              "prefix": "https:\/\/ss3.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/parks_outdoors\/park_",
              "suffix": ".png"
            },
            "primary": true
          }
        ],
        "verified": false,
        "stats": {
          "checkinsCount": 1508,
          "usersCount": 1161,
          "tipCount": 10
        },
        "specials": {
          "count": 0,
          "items": [

          ]
        },
        "hereNow": {
          "count": 0,
          "summary": "Nobody here",
          "groups": [

          ]
        },
        "referralId": "v-1429381004"
      },
      {
        "id": "3fd66200f964a520daf11ee3",
        "name": "South Street Seaport",
        "contact": {
          "phone": "2127327678",
          "formattedPhone": "(212) 732-7678",
          "twitter": "theseaport"
        },
        "location": {
          "address": "South St",
          "crossStreet": "Pier 17",
          "lat": 40.70566047104496,
          "lng": -74.00287628173828,
          "distance": 675,
          "postalCode": "10038",
          "cc": "US",
          "city": "New York",
          "state": "NY",
          "country": "United States",
          "formattedAddress": [
            "South St (Pier 17)",
            "New York, NY 10038",
            "United States"
          ]
        },
        "categories": [
          {
            "id": "4bf58dd8d48988d1e0941735",
            "name": "Harbor \/ Marina",
            "pluralName": "Harbors \/ Marinas",
            "shortName": "Harbor \/ Marina",
            "icon": {
              "prefix": "https:\/\/ss3.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/parks_outdoors\/harbor_",
              "suffix": ".png"
            },
            "primary": true
          }
        ],
        "verified": true,
        "stats": {
          "checkinsCount": 45850,
          "usersCount": 29726,
          "tipCount": 180
        },
        "url": "http:\/\/www.southstreetseaport.com",
        "specials": {
          "count": 0,
          "items": [

          ]
        },
        "events": {
          "count": 1,
          "summary": "Hornblower",
          "items": [
            {
              "id": "550a2152498e6adfd409dfa4",
              "name": "Hornblower",
              "categories": [

              ],
              "allDay": true,
              "date": 1429345800,
              "timeZone": "America\/New_York",
              "text": "",
              "url": "http:\/\/www.voiceplaces.com\/new-york\/hornblower-4897577-e",
              "images": [

              ],
              "provider": {
                "name": "Village Voice",
                "iconUrl": {
                  "prefix": "https:\/\/playfoursquare.s3.amazonaws.com\/events\/images\/partners\/villagevoice\/",
                  "sizes": [
                    20,
                    40
                  ],
                  "name": "\/logo.png"
                },
                "urlText": "more info"
              },
              "stats": {
                "checkinsCount": 0,
                "usersCount": 0
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "hereNow": {
          "count": 5,
          "summary": "5 people are checked in here",
          "groups": [
            {
              "type": "others",
              "name": "Other people here",
              "count": 5,
              "items": [

              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "venuePage": {
          "id": "59071427"
        },
        "storeId": "",
        "referralId": "v-1429381004"
      },
      {
        "id": "42377700f964a52024201fe3",
        "name": "Brooklyn Heights Promenade",
        "contact": {

        },
        "location": {
          "address": "Columbia Heights",
          "crossStreet": "btwn Remsen & Orange",
          "lat": 40.69829137715981,
          "lng": -73.99663209915161,
          "distance": 342,
          "postalCode": "11201",
          "cc": "US",
          "city": "Brooklyn",
          "state": "NY",
          "country": "United States",
          "formattedAddress": [
            "Columbia Heights (btwn Remsen & Orange)",
            "Brooklyn, NY 11201",
            "United States"
          ]
        },
        "categories": [
          {
            "id": "4bf58dd8d48988d163941735",
            "name": "Park",
            "pluralName": "Parks",
            "shortName": "Park",
            "icon": {
              "prefix": "https:\/\/ss3.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/parks_outdoors\/park_",
              "suffix": ".png"
            },
            "primary": true
          }
        ],
        "verified": false,
        "stats": {
          "checkinsCount": 18073,
          "usersCount": 8755,
          "tipCount": 138
        },
        "url": "http:\/\/nyharborparks.org\/visit\/brhe.html",
        "specials": {
          "count": 0,
          "items": [

          ]
        },
        "hereNow": {
          "count": 0,
          "summary": "Nobody here",
          "groups": [

          ]
        },
        "referralId": "v-1429381004"
      },
      {
        "id": "53ff2935498e161412b3e871",
        "name": "Brooklyn Bridge Park - Pier 2 Yoga Court",
        "contact": {

        },
        "location": {
          "lat": 40.700111,
          "lng": -73.999185,
          "distance": 69,
          "cc": "US",
          "city": "Brooklyn",
          "state": "NY",
          "country": "United States",
          "formattedAddress": [
            "Brooklyn, NY",
            "United States"
          ]
        },
        "categories": [
          {
            "id": "4bf58dd8d48988d102941735",
            "name": "Yoga Studio",
            "pluralName": "Yoga Studios",
            "shortName": "Yoga Studio",
            "icon": {
              "prefix": "https:\/\/ss3.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/shops\/gym_yogastudio_",
              "suffix": ".png"
            },
            "primary": true
          }
        ],
        "verified": false,
        "stats": {
          "checkinsCount": 6,
          "usersCount": 3,
          "tipCount": 0
        },
        "specials": {
          "count": 0,
          "items": [

          ]
        },
        "hereNow": {
          "count": 0,
          "summary": "Nobody here",
          "groups": [

          ]
        },
        "referralId": "v-1429381004"
      },
      {
        "id": "4f2c1bbae4b0ccfb1d99b510",
        "name": "kk hair salon",
        "contact": {

        },
        "location": {
          "lat": 40.69956588745117,
          "lng": -74.00108337402344,
          "distance": 103,
          "cc": "US",
          "state": "New York",
          "country": "United States",
          "formattedAddress": [
            "New York",
            "United States"
          ]
        },
        "categories": [
          {
            "id": "4bf58dd8d48988d110951735",
            "name": "Salon \/ Barbershop",
            "pluralName": "Salons \/ Barbershops",
            "shortName": "Salon \/ Barbershop",
            "icon": {
              "prefix": "https:\/\/ss3.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/shops\/salon_barber_",
              "suffix": ".png"
            },
            "primary": true
          }
        ],
        "verified": false,
        "stats": {
          "checkinsCount": 1,
          "usersCount": 1,
          "tipCount": 0
        },
        "specials": {
          "count": 0,
          "items": [

          ]
        },
        "hereNow": {
          "count": 0,
          "summary": "Nobody here",
          "groups": [

          ]
        },
        "referralId": "v-1429381004"
      },
      {
        "id": "540ca09f498e9d0f44e40791",
        "name": "Smorgasburg at Brooklyn Bridge Park - Pier 2",
        "contact": {
          "twitter": "bkflea"
        },
        "location": {
          "address": "Pier 2 (at Brooklyn Bridge Park)",
          "lat": 40.69938593942123,
          "lng": -73.99699733176632,
          "distance": 262,
          "cc": "US",
          "city": "Brooklyn",
          "state": "NY",
          "country": "United States",
          "formattedAddress": [
            "Pier 2 (at Brooklyn Bridge Park)",
            "Brooklyn, NY",
            "United States"
          ]
        },
        "categories": [
          {
            "id": "53e0feef498e5aac066fd8a9",
            "name": "Street Food Gathering",
            "pluralName": "Street Food Gatherings",
            "shortName": "Street Food Gathering",
            "icon": {
              "prefix": "https:\/\/ss3.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/food\/streetfood_",
              "suffix": ".png"
            },
            "primary": true
          }
        ],
        "verified": false,
        "stats": {
          "checkinsCount": 545,
          "usersCount": 523,
          "tipCount": 6
        },
        "specials": {
          "count": 0,
          "items": [

          ]
        },
        "hereNow": {
          "count": 0,
          "summary": "Nobody here",
          "groups": [

          ]
        },
        "referralId": "v-1429381004"
      },
      {
        "id": "3fd66200f964a520e9e81ee3",
        "name": "Grimaldi's Pizzeria",
        "contact": {
          "phone": "7188584300",
          "formattedPhone": "(718) 858-4300",
          "twitter": "grimaldisnyc"
        },
        "location": {
          "address": "1 Front St",
          "crossStreet": "at Cadman Plaza W",
          "lat": 40.70250515261926,
          "lng": -73.9933359887217,
          "distance": 627,
          "postalCode": "11201",
          "cc": "US",
          "city": "Brooklyn",
          "state": "NY",
          "country": "United States",
          "formattedAddress": [
            "1 Front St (at Cadman Plaza W)",
            "Brooklyn, NY 11201",
            "United States"
          ]
        },
        "categories": [
          {
            "id": "4bf58dd8d48988d1ca941735",
            "name": "Pizza Place",
            "pluralName": "Pizza Places",
            "shortName": "Pizza",
            "icon": {
              "prefix": "https:\/\/ss3.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/food\/pizza_",
              "suffix": ".png"
            },
            "primary": true
          }
        ],
        "verified": false,
        "stats": {
          "checkinsCount": 21973,
          "usersCount": 18381,
          "tipCount": 459
        },
        "url": "http:\/\/www.grimaldis.com",
        "hasMenu": true,
        "menu": {
          "type": "Menu",
          "label": "Menu",
          "anchor": "View Menu",
          "url": "https:\/\/foursquare.com\/v\/grimaldis-pizzeria\/3fd66200f964a520e9e81ee3\/menu",
          "mobileUrl": "https:\/\/foursquare.com\/v\/3fd66200f964a520e9e81ee3\/device_menu"
        },
        "specials": {
          "count": 0,
          "items": [

          ]
        },
        "hereNow": {
          "count": 0,
          "summary": "Nobody here",
          "groups": [

          ]
        },
        "referralId": "v-1429381004"
      },
      {
        "id": "4c34a57da0ced13a9379186e",
        "name": "Under The Brooklyn Bridge",
        "contact": {
          "twitter": "nyc_dot",
          "facebook": "166279802886",
          "facebookUsername": "NYCDOT",
          "facebookName": "NYC DOT"
        },
        "location": {
          "address": "Brooklyn Bridge",
          "crossStreet": "FDR Dr",
          "lat": 40.703475724581324,
          "lng": -73.99405334200495,
          "distance": 633,
          "postalCode": "11201",
          "cc": "US",
          "city": "Brooklyn",
          "state": "NY",
          "country": "United States",
          "formattedAddress": [
            "Brooklyn Bridge (FDR Dr)",
            "Brooklyn, NY 11201",
            "United States"
          ]
        },
        "categories": [
          {
            "id": "4bf58dd8d48988d165941735",
            "name": "Scenic Lookout",
            "pluralName": "Scenic Lookouts",
            "shortName": "Scenic Lookout",
            "icon": {
              "prefix": "https:\/\/ss3.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/parks_outdoors\/sceniclookout_",
              "suffix": ".png"
            },
            "primary": true
          }
        ],
        "verified": true,
        "stats": {
          "checkinsCount": 7406,
          "usersCount": 5831,
          "tipCount": 31
        },
        "url": "http:\/\/www.nyc.gov\/dot",
        "specials": {
          "count": 0,
          "items": [

          ]
        },
        "hereNow": {
          "count": 0,
          "summary": "Nobody here",
          "groups": [

          ]
        },
        "referralId": "v-1429381004"
      },
      {
        "id": "4cb92bdc7148f04d9336d5ab",
        "name": "Livys apartment !",
        "contact": {

        },
        "location": {
          "address": "95 Wall St",
          "crossStreet": "Water st",
          "lat": 40.700249,
          "lng": -74.001442,
          "distance": 124,
          "postalCode": "10005",
          "cc": "US",
          "city": "New York",
          "state": "NY",
          "country": "United States",
          "formattedAddress": [
            "95 Wall St (Water st)",
            "New York, NY 10005",
            "United States"
          ]
        },
        "categories": [
          {
            "id": "4bf58dd8d48988d1a3941735",
            "name": "College Residence Hall",
            "pluralName": "College Residence Halls",
            "shortName": "Residence Hall",
            "icon": {
              "prefix": "https:\/\/ss3.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/education\/residencehall_",
              "suffix": ".png"
            },
            "primary": true
          }
        ],
        "verified": false,
        "stats": {
          "checkinsCount": 1,
          "usersCount": 1,
          "tipCount": 0
        },
        "specials": {
          "count": 0,
          "items": [

          ]
        },
        "hereNow": {
          "count": 0,
          "summary": "Nobody here",
          "groups": [

          ]
        },
        "referralId": "v-1429381004"
      },
      {
        "id": "4c5435bf4623be9a62ee66f2",
        "name": "Brooklyn Bridge Park - Pier 4",
        "contact": {

        },
        "location": {
          "address": "214 Furman St",
          "crossStreet": "Montague St",
          "lat": 40.69662731765942,
          "lng": -73.99846644034649,
          "distance": 397,
          "postalCode": "11201",
          "cc": "US",
          "city": "Brooklyn",
          "state": "NY",
          "country": "United States",
          "formattedAddress": [
            "214 Furman St (Montague St)",
            "Brooklyn, NY 11201",
            "United States"
          ]
        },
        "categories": [
          {
            "id": "4bf58dd8d48988d163941735",
            "name": "Park",
            "pluralName": "Parks",
            "shortName": "Park",
            "icon": {
              "prefix": "https:\/\/ss3.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/parks_outdoors\/park_",
              "suffix": ".png"
            },
            "primary": true
          }
        ],
        "verified": false,
        "stats": {
          "checkinsCount": 1196,
          "usersCount": 945,
          "tipCount": 3
        },
        "url": "http:\/\/www.brooklynbridgepark.org\/the-park\/future-park\/pier-4",
        "specials": {
          "count": 0,
          "items": [

          ]
        },
        "hereNow": {
          "count": 0,
          "summary": "Nobody here",
          "groups": [

          ]
        },
        "referralId": "v-1429381004"
      },
      {
        "id": "5054eb43e4b04ed4f0dd1b30",
        "name": "La cabana",
        "contact": {

        },
        "location": {
          "lat": 40.69875,
          "lng": -73.99953,
          "distance": 144,
          "cc": "US",
          "state": "New York",
          "country": "United States",
          "formattedAddress": [
            "New York",
            "United States"
          ]
        },
        "categories": [
          {
            "id": "4bf58dd8d48988d154941735",
            "name": "Cuban Restaurant",
            "pluralName": "Cuban Restaurants",
            "shortName": "Cuban",
            "icon": {
              "prefix": "https:\/\/ss3.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/food\/cuban_",
              "suffix": ".png"
            },
            "primary": true
          }
        ],
        "verified": false,
        "stats": {
          "checkinsCount": 4,
          "usersCount": 4,
          "tipCount": 1
        },
        "specials": {
          "count": 0,
          "items": [

          ]
        },
        "hereNow": {
          "count": 0,
          "summary": "Nobody here",
          "groups": [

          ]
        },
        "referralId": "v-1429381004"
      },
      {
        "id": "4ae62580f964a52011a521e3",
        "name": "Danish Seamen's Church",
        "contact": {

        },
        "location": {
          "address": "102 Willow St",
          "lat": 40.698023159650134,
          "lng": -73.99568889745463,
          "distance": 425,
          "postalCode": "11201",
          "cc": "US",
          "city": "Brooklyn",
          "state": "NY",
          "country": "United States",
          "formattedAddress": [
            "102 Willow St",
            "Brooklyn, NY 11201",
            "United States"
          ]
        },
        "categories": [
          {
            "id": "4bf58dd8d48988d132941735",
            "name": "Church",
            "pluralName": "Churches",
            "shortName": "Church",
            "icon": {
              "prefix": "https:\/\/ss3.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/building\/religious_church_",
              "suffix": ".png"
            },
            "primary": true
          }
        ],
        "verified": false,
        "stats": {
          "checkinsCount": 106,
          "usersCount": 71,
          "tipCount": 0
        },
        "specials": {
          "count": 0,
          "items": [

          ]
        },
        "hereNow": {
          "count": 0,
          "summary": "Nobody here",
          "groups": [

          ]
        },
        "referralId": "v-1429381004"
      }
    ],
    "confident": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check [foursquare venues search](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search) parameters correctly, you used "category" parameter but the correct parameter is "**categoryId**" (*not* categoryid). So you should change your url to:

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?client_id=PUT_YOUR_CLIENT_ID_HERE&client_secret=PUT_YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET_HERE&v=20140714&ll=40.7,-74&radius=1000&categoryId=4d4b7105d754a06374d81259

Comment: Hey.  Sorry for the delay.  Tried your solution and it totally worked.  Didn't know header data could be case sensitive.  Thanks so much!